# Server needs in order to stream mp3 files to 1000 of users

Tags: android, iphone, server, audio-streaming

What is the best server solution for an iPhone/Android app that plays mp3 podcast files without overloading the server.  Can this be done with GoDaddy Servers?  Finding that during the day the sever is just fine, however when a new podcast is released the server come to a crawl.

Comment: one option is soundcloud and use the API for streaming -- https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide

Comment: You don't need a big server, you need a CDN. Use something like S3/cloud front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a protocol standpoint, any HTTP server will work fine.

For scale, a 1,000 users is not a lot unless they're all requesting that file simultaneously.  Any cheap hosting should be able to handle such load.  Just be aware of any bandwidth limits.

If it were me, I would upload that media to an S3 bucket on AWS.  From there, you can use [CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) to serve files from that bucket from a geographically distributed network of servers.

Comment: Thanks Brad.  I am using a WordPress site today and when we release a new show at 10:00 the server comes to a crawl (because 1000's of subscribers are accessing the same files - I assume; during the day the streaming works just fine).  I didn't want to have to use an AWS server unless I knew it would handle the streaming where as the GoDaddy Wordpress server would not.